# Need a RegEx to put in my password validator

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, passwords

**RegEx for: At least 2 uppercase letters, at least 2 digits and at least 1 special character (?.*!:)**

I can't seem to find a solution here (excuse me if there is one, but I've searched and couldn't find it). Basically I've made a web chat for my homework in ASP.NET and the only thing missing is checking for password strength. I have a validator and need to put in a RegEx to check the mentioned conditions. I've tried doing it myself but I'm really clumsy at it.

**Example password:** paSSword?123

Thanks for help and explanations in advance :)

**EDIT:** So far I've come to something like this, but it doesn't seem to work.

`^(?=.{8,50}$)(?=(.*[!?:.*]){1,})(?=(.*[A-Z]){2,})(?=(.*[a-z]))(?=(.*[0-9]){2,}).*`

First part checks the length, second the provided special characters so there is at least one.. and so on and so on.

Comment: [The real question is why impose such a restriction on your users?](https://xkcd.com/936/)

Comment: Just following instruction from my professor. I know, it's silly. Most common restriction is 1 upper and 1 digit, right?

Comment: That is true, here's an example of one upper, one special, and one digit (also 8 length). `^(?:(?=.*[a-z])(?:(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\d\W])|(?=.*\W)(?=.*\d))|(?=.*\W)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)).{8,}$`. Considering that it's an "*instruction from my professor.*", you should probably work it out yourself, hence I have written a similar answer here and not the same one

Comment: Oh, right, totally forgot to add it in the description. I edited it now.

Comment: So it looks like you're limiting the input to having these characters `?.*!:`, is there a reason for the example having `$`

Comment: Ah, I also edited the example now. Sorry for the inconveniences.

Answer (score 1):

Regex isn´t good on counting the occurence of letters within a string. You should use some LINQ for this:

```
int totalNumber = myPassword.Length;
int upperCaseChars = myPassword.Count(x => char.IsUpper(x));
int lowerDigitChars = myPassword.Count(x => char.IsNumber(x));
int specialChars = myPassword.Count(x => x == '.' || x == ':' || ...);
return upperCaseChars >= 2 && lowerCaseChars >= 2 and specialChars >= 1;
```

For searching for a special character you *may* use a regex however:

```
var r = new Regex("[\?\.\*!:]");
int specialChars = myPassword.Count(x => r.IsMatch(x.ToString());
```

However this seems cumbersome also.

Last approach would be to use `char.IsSymbol` which checks for many (but of course not all) special characters. If this is enoguh for you...

If this solution doesn´t work for you you can also write an extension-method to check if a character is a special one:

```
public static IsSpecial(this char c) 
{
    return c == '.' || c == ':' || ...
}
```

Now you can use the count as follows:

```
int specialChars = myPassword.Count(x => x.IsSpecial());
```

Comment: Alternatively to checking `char.IsSymbol` you could always, using the same logic as the regex in my comment, have `int specialChars = myPassword.Count(x => !(char.IsLower(x)) && !(char.IsUpper(x)) && !(char.IsNumber(x)));` though that might not be too reliable

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre Well, it´s better than comparing for every single cpecial character which would be very many. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Really appreciate your effort. While I could do it your way which is really convenient (and I've thought of it already) I think given we just covered this section at our class yesterday it is necessary we do it via a RegEx used in Visual Studio validator properties.

Comment: Then everything that comes to my mind is to check *every* single char against the regex as I already mentioned, however you´ll still need the `Count`. There is no real *pattern* which a regex could evaluate. All your characters can come in an arbitrary order making it nearly impossible to use a regex here.